# Spring, Maven Dependency and Jar Issues

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-mvc, maven-3, m2eclipse

I had made Spring MVC and Hibernate application by taking reference from 
[here](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-mvc-3-hibernate-annotations.html)

on the office system(running Ubuntu). It's running fine and showing no problems.

When I copy and save the application on my home system (running windows xp), error shown that some jars failed to transfer.

Also, this dependecy

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

doesn't work on my xp system.

When I changes the hibernate version to 3.6.x, jars successfully transferred.

I am running maven 3 and m2eclipse on both systems.

Kindly Advice..

Comment: can you run maven with the `-X` switch and state the nature of the error occuring while trying to fetch the dependencies from your XP system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do mvn [install:install](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html) to install the jar manually into the .m2 directory . When you try to package the app , you'll see a build failure with a recommendation that you do an mvn install:install . Download the the jar manually from [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.3.2.GA/) , do a mvn install:install followed by mvn eclipse:eclipse and refresh the workspace .

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have some files in your local repository on your Ubuntu system `$HOME/.m2/repository` that don't exist on your XP machine `c:\Documents and Settings\$USER\.m2\repository`.

You can either copy the files from the linux repo or use `mvn install:install-file` to update your windows repo manually.

hope that helped

Comment: hmm after looking up the jars in the maven repo i see that hibernate-core 3.3.2.GA is avaible on central at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/3.3.2.GA so you should be able to download them while building with maven.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the local maven repository under windows (I only use windows, I can not speak for the other systems) strange. This means it does not uodate former not found artefact.

In this cases you have the subdirect directory for the artefact in you local `.m2` directory but it is almost empty (except 2 files). If this happen I delete that directory and then invoke maven (for example `mvn compile`) again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this by adding the Spring repository to your pom file.

```
<repository>
   <em> <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id></em>
    <name>EBR Spring Release Repository</name>
    <url>http:// repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
</repository>
<repository>
    <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
    <name>EBR External Release Repository</name>
    <url>http:// repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
</repository>
```